# Асинхронный вызов без ожидания завершения выполнения

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть у меня условный кусок кода. Хочу, чтобы он что-то делал, потом вызвал асинхронно какой-то другой метод, не дожидался его выполнения и продолжил что-то делать.

К примеру: 
1. Вывод на консоль "Старт!" 
2. Вызов метода, который долго выполняется. 
3. Вывод на консоль "Конец!"

Надо, чтобы на консоли отобразились сразу "Старт! Конец!" без ожидания выполнения долгого метода.

Как это сделать?

Пытался нагуглить, но выходили способы с BeginInvoke, а это вроде старый подход. Может есть способ с async/await?

Если вызвать метод без `await`, то он сделает то, чего я хочу, или же вызовет и выполнит метод синхронно?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("start"); Task.Run(() => {/* your code here */}); Console.WriteLine("end");`

Comment: @tym32167 а как внутри этого самого `your code here` правильно вызвать асинхронный метод?

Comment: просто вызовите его и всё, `Task.Run(() => DoSomethingAsync());`

Comment: Можно и без await, но в этом случае асинхронно выполнится только действительно асинхронный код. Синхронная часть выполнится синхронно, а если результат уже есть, то может и вся задача уже выполнится синхронно.